# Backpack Laravel Filterable Crud List in Tabbed Content

Tags: laravel-backpack

I have two Crud Controllers, Project & PurchaseOrders.

When I display a particular project content *(say URL /project/2/show)*, its related purchase orders are displayed in table format in one of the tabs like picture below:

[image]

Since there will be a lot of purchase orders within same project, I need the table above to be filterable, like in the method SetupListOperation() in PurchaseOrders Controller like picture below:

[image]

Basically, how do I put PurchaseOrders Controller List Operation within a Project content Tab?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, in Backpack version 4.x / 5.x, you can't. The ListOperation wasn't designed to be used that way, so it will be very difficult to do. It will be faster to just code that feature yourself, with a limited set of features - only the ones you need.

The main reason why it wouldn't be simple is that both the ListOperation and the CreateOperation / UpdateOperation would be using the `CRUD` singleton, whereas you need to show/manipulate entries in two different entities (projects and purchase orders).

The Backpack team is working on a feature that you could use for this (a "table" widget you can include anywhere, including there), but it will probably take 2-3 more months to launch.

Also, there's a Backpack add-on offering something similar (see https://github.com/izica/relations-widgets-for-backpack ) but it's meant for the Show operation (not Update) and it doesn't include filtering, from what I can tell.

So the best you can do, in my opinion, is to just add some rough filters to your custom view - they'll work just like you want, and when an official solution becomes available, you can use that then.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Well, I think I'll just skip adding Tabbed content. 

But instead, add a GET parameter in PurchaseOrders Controller List so that when I click Orders list in Project detail, I got redirected to PO list page with Crud Where Clause from the get parameter. This way, my client can browse/filter only orders from particular project.

Cant wait for the a "table" widget, hopefully it will be released with version 5.x free/pro